# I am using brfv4 with ThreeJS and trying to put the glasses for 2 faces but it is not working, it works only for 1 face

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using brfv4 library with ThreeJS and trying to put the glasses for two faces but it is not working. It works only for one face. I have also tried to change the variable value `numFacesToTrack` to 2, by default it is 1, but it is not working.

I also want to know how can I create my own modal of glasses and how can I load that one.

```
function exampleCode() {
"use strict";

var t3d = brfv4Example.drawing3d.t3d;
var numFacesToTrack = 2;
// var numFacesToTrack = 1;
function loadModels() {

    if(t3d) {

        // Remove all models and load new ones.

        t3d.removeAll();
        t3d.loadOcclusionHead("assets/brfv4_occlusion_head.json", numFacesToTrack);
        t3d.loadModel("assets/brfv4_model.json", numFacesToTrack);
    }
}

brfv4Example.initCurrentExample = function(brfManager, resolution) {

    brfManager.init(resolution, resolution, brfv4Example.appId);
    brfManager.setNumFacesToTrack(numFacesToTrack);

    // Relax starting conditions to eventually find more faces.

    var maxFaceSize = resolution.height;

    if(resolution.width < resolution.height) {
        maxFaceSize = resolution.width;
    }

    brfManager.setFaceDetectionParams(      maxFaceSize * 0.20, maxFaceSize * 1.00, 12, 8);
    brfManager.setFaceTrackingStartParams(  maxFaceSize * 0.20, maxFaceSize * 1.00, 32, 35, 32);
    brfManager.setFaceTrackingResetParams(  maxFaceSize * 0.15, maxFaceSize * 1.00, 40, 55, 32);

    loadModels();
};

brfv4Example.updateCurrentExample = function(brfManager, imageData, draw) {

    brfManager.update(imageData);

    if(t3d) t3d.hideAll(); // Hide 3d models. Only show them on top of tracked faces.

    draw.clear();

    var faces = brfManager.getFaces();

    for(var i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) {

        var face = faces[i];

        if(face.state === brfv4.BRFState.FACE_TRACKING) {

            // Draw the 68 facial feature points as reference.

            draw.drawVertices(face.vertices, 2.0, false, 0x00a0ff, 0.4);

            // Set the 3D model according to the tracked results.

            if(t3d) t3d.update(i, face, true);
        }
    }

    if(t3d) { t3d.render(); }
};

brfv4Example.dom.updateCodeSnippet(exampleCode + "");

brfv4Example.dom.updateHeadline("BRFv4 - advanced - face_tracking - ThreeJS example.\n" +
    "Tracks up to " + numFacesToTrack + " faces and puts glasses on them.");
     }

The result is something like this
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like you have debug tracking (the dots) for one face. Are you able to get that working for two faces? If not, that's a question for brfv4. As far as loading your own model, there are many [examples](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=loader) for many different formats.

Comment: no, I have checked it for two faces but its not working for two faces, the glasses are showing with only one face.